# Getting root on a Sony TV?

Tags: python, root, busybox, sony

I recently read this post over at Hack a Day [Getting root on a Sony TV](http://hackaday.com/2012/06/20/getting-root-on-a-sony-tv/), which uses a script that can be found [here](https://github.com/CFSworks/nimue) for use on Sony Bravia TVs. The script uses BusyBox and my question is based on the README found [here](https://github.com/CFSworks/nimue/tree/master/busybox). I have two questions about this: 1. What are the steps I have to take in order to compile BusyBox for the mipsel architecture? 2. How do I include the GLibc / Linux kernel versions for your TV in my BusyBox binary?

Has anyone else gotten this trick to work successfully?

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling for another architecture is called *cross compiling*, but of course you would have read that on the [Busybox FAQ](http://www.busybox.net/FAQ.html). Not to mention the link provided there to cross-compilers for all architectures you could ask for.

You could try find a pre-built MIPS binary, the best would be to ask the Busybox list directly if in doubt :)